# Can I specify TypeScript type constraints in terms of operations on global methods?

Tags: typescript

For instance, can I define a string type

```
type BloodPressureMeasurementString = string;
```

and an object type

```
type BloodPressureMeasurement = { systolic: number; diastolic: number; }
```

and specify that `JSON.parse()` on the string type yields the object type, and vice versa with `JSON.stringify()`?

```
let bp: BloodPressureMeasurement = { systolic: 120, diastolic: 80 };
let bpString = JSON.stringfy(bp); // type of bpString is BloodPressureMeasurementString
let bpCopy = JSON.parse(bpString); // type of bpCopy is BloodPressureMeasurement
```

Currently, this is done with type assertions or enforcement code at the `JSON.parse()`/`JSON.stringify()` call site. I would like to be able to move these to the place where the string resource is created (such as when it's downloaded from the Internet).

Comment: Do you have any more questions? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @jperl No, you understood the question correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question!

Let's see how we can do this safely.

[image]

```
type BloodPressureMeasurementString = string;

type BloodPressureMeasurement = { systolic: number; diastolic: number; }

interface JSON { // extends JSON interface through declaration merging
    stringify(val: BloodPressureMeasurement): BloodPressureMeasurementString
    parse(val: BloodPressureMeasurementString): BloodPressureMeasurement
}

var a = JSON.stringify({ systolic: 2, diastolic: 3 }); //string
var b = JSON.parse('{"systolic":2,"diastolic":3}'); //BloodPressureMeasurement
var c = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'); //BloodPressureMeasurement!!
```

Does not really work as expected =/ As you might already know, Typescript type system is structural not nominal. There is not a single difference between `BloodPressureMeasurementString` and `string`. So we need a way to simulate nominal types.

Let's how we can do this with some adjustments<sup>1</sup>

```
type BloodPressureMeasurementString = string & {readonly brand: unique symbol};
```

And there you have it, `a` is now of type `BloodPressureMeasurementString`.

Typescript is smart enough to infer which overload is more relevant:

[image]

[image]

[image]

However, please note that you won't be able to do something like this

```
var variable: BloodPressureMeasurementString = "some string" //type '"some string"' is not assignable to type 'BloodPressureMeasurementString'
```

which was to be expected. You'll have to use type assertions. We could use a function to help us create a BloodPressureMeasurementString.

```
//types and values live in separate namespaces so we can have the same name both for the function and for the type
function BloodPressureMeasurementString(str: string) { 
    return str as BloodPressureMeasurementString
}
```

and then we can do

```
var variable: BloodPressureMeasurementString = BloodPressureMeasurementString("some string") // OK
```

[Typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgNgewQEwAoCcIGcsFdMCyEAhnpgLYQB2wAysOgJZUDmUAvFFg82wGRQA3pmLIEVOCCgAjdMSrIAXFFxVGAR1zQsIctIRwAvgG4AUKdCRYiFBmxkIRUvgiUaHIVxDcDjAMbKVLh6EOjGUMiMpMC+AVBBIWFQhubMwKEAZsR+0ABStADyAHKeAPSlUHAQwFD5xVAA1lQIAO5QxPq4NQj4UAgAbqGIolimAJDcTKyMGSAAFP3EcMrwSGiYOC5ODm7AAJQrNuv2WyQ71HQ8rONgxOhYEAtLh2t2m4RnLrv0UywH1q8Ng5tl8LqYUqZFuh2h46kUAHSTXgzeaCLw+OD+ZQAJgANBEohisVAAMzJPbhcqrWxA07OCgXH68Ux+cRYAwQeGIFhzYgUyF3GSwwoI273R58ymlanHd6OT4MmgC6F+YXFeFih5zADkaIARFRiJQ9Yo9bkEAALKh6-F64gsCAmkkABltfkYoBNeqKEDaAE0EOgGnrDNqKVByu0qCBzBlVH5gIxxACaScPvTXIyrjzJsokaw9kJxphgPgqFwGO0sCnZcCFZmaEzrhCoVAoVFpFUXqm5SDFZdfh4ZW86xnvtm5nr2ZQK789XsgA)

<sup>1</sup><sub>You might be wondering what's that {readonly brand: unique symbol}. Its purpose is twofold: first we don't want our type to be confounded with a string and we don't wan't it to be confounded with a similar type. We can't write string & number which results to never, if we wrote instead string & {  }, it would be confounded with a string and if we wrote string & { brand: symbol }, another similar type (named differently but having string & { brand: symbol }) could be confounded with our type. The unique (which requires readonly) will not allow this.</sub>

Comment: It took a bit for me to try this out, but it works great! Thank you!